# Detecting a square object from an image using OpenCv in android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

[image: Detecting Square Image from the picture]

Below is the code i used

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView iv;
    protected BaseLoaderCallback OpenCVCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    System.out.println("tester");
                    onOpenCVReady();
                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




}
private void OutputGrayMatToFile(Mat mGaryMat, String Filename)
{
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBelow);
    Mat mRgba = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mGaryMat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA, 4);
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.cols(), mRgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmp);
    img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0,this,OpenCVCallBack);
}

protected void onOpenCVReady(){
    //this should crash if opencv is not loaded
    Mat img = new Mat();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "opencv ready", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Bitmap footbm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img);
  //  Bitmap footbm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    Mat footMat = new Mat();
    //convert bitmap to opencv Mat
    Utils.bitmapToMat(footbm, footMat);

    //Convert to Gray image
    Mat footGrayMat = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(footMat, footGrayMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, 1);

    //Do canny
    Mat outCannyMat = new Mat();
    Imgproc.Canny(footGrayMat, outCannyMat, 80, 100, 3, false);

    //output to file
    OutputGrayMatToFile(outCannyMat, "Canny");
}
```

}

**Question**
How can i get the square image from it I am not getting any idea as This is my first time using OpenCV and Image Processing..
So far i reached this point and quite frustrated with it or Anyone please tell me about any other better way with Object detection in an Image

Comment: Also note you might get better answers if you provide a **Minimal working example** and not just a code dump

Comment: Hy Thanku this link is gonna help me a lot

Comment: @TheLethalCoder now shall i delete the question or what??

Comment: If you feel like the other question helps you, you could mark this as a duplicate of the other (not sure if you can yet). Or simply just delete yes. Also note that you can upvote the other question and the answer that helps you. As long as it does of course